# Rewrite URL with slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess

How to rewrite the URL if i input something like `http://someone.com/hi/hello/yeah` and i expect the result would be `http://someone.com/?u=hi_hello_yeah`

this is i wrote so far and it only replace a url that doesn't have slash "/"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and also, i want that if a user will input `http://someone.com/hi/hello/yeah`, it will redirect to `http://someone.com/hi_hello_yeah`

Comment: does the link always like `http://someone.com/.../...`? can it be using `.info`, `.net`, `.gov`? or worst case using ip like `192.168.10.123:8080/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the last line of your `rewrite` rules.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

seems should be corrected to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

I see two questions in your post:

1. You want to get the ***slash-to-underscore*** converted URL value.
2. When someone types in `/hi/hello/year` the URL should be ***redirected*** to `/hi_hello_year`.

**URL rewrite** and **redirect** are two independent actions.

### 1. Slash-to-underscore conversion

You already have `$_GET['u']` variable which holds `/hi/hello/year`.
Simply `str_replace`ing it will give you the converted URI string.

```
<?
// this is the landing index.php page specified in the last rewrite rule. 

// should be "/hi/hello/year" for "/hi/hello/year" URL request. 
$rewritten_uri = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : '';

// converting slashes to underscores.
$converted_uri = str_replace( '/', '_', $rewritten_uri );

// the string begins and/or ends with a slash, so remove it.
$ready_to_use_uri = trim( $converted_uri, '_' );

?>
```

### 2. Redirecting to a new URL

Someone who typed in `/hi/hello/year` should see a new `/hi_hello_year` URL in his/her browser.
This involves `header( "Location: ..." )`;

```
<?
$new_url = '/' . $ready_to_use_uri; // which came from the above code
header( 'Location: ' . $new_url );
exit(); // unless you have some more work to do.
?>
```

### 3. Combined

However, above redirection is based on the assumption that the server has `hi_hello_year` document, otherwise it could lead to an endless `rewrite`-`redirect` loop. Let's combine and add a safety measure.

```
<?
// this is the landing index.php page specified in the last rewrite rule. 

// should be "/hi/hello/year" for "/hi/hello/year" URL request. 
$rewritten_uri = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : '';

// converting slashes to underscores.
$converted_uri = str_replace( '/', '_', $rewritten_uri );

// the string begins and/or ends with a slash, so remove it.
$ready_to_use_uri = trim( $converted_uri, '_' );

// redirect only when such file exists 
if ( file_exist( $ready_to_use_uri ) )
{
  header( 'Location: /' . $ready_to_use_uri );
  exit(); // unless you have some more work to do.
}

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "The document '" . $ready_to_use_uri . "' is not found on this server";
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is tricky as it requires recursive application of rewrite rules.**

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# this recursive rule will be applied as many times as the /s in the URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1_$2 [L]

# this rule will be applied once all /s have been replaced by _
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```